# Cross section for Hydrogen molecule formation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, hydrogen, scattering-cross-section, quantum-chemistry

I have been searching for theoretical articles that calculate the hydrogen formation cross section $\sigma(H+H \rightarrow H_2)$, but I found  nothing. Can anyone suggest me articles or computer programs that calculate this cross section?